# Variability/randomness of Support Vector Machine model scores in Python's scikitlearn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I am testing several ML classification models, in this case Support Vector Machines. I have basic knowledge about the SVM algorithm and how it works.

I am using the built-in breast cancer dataset from scikit learn.

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
```

Using the code below:

```
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(cancer.data, cancer.target, 
                                                    stratify=cancer.target, random_state=42)
clf2 = LinearSVC(C=0.01).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf3 = LinearSVC(C=0.1).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf4 = LinearSVC(C=1).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf5 = LinearSVC(C=10).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf6 = LinearSVC(C=100).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

When printing the scores as in:

```
print("Model training score with C=0.01:\n{:.3f}".format(clf2.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Model testing score with C=0.01:\n{:.3f}".format(clf2.score(X_test, y_test)))
print("------------------------------")
print("Model training score with C=0.1:\n{:.3f}".format(clf3.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Model testing score with C=0.1:\n{:.3f}".format(clf3.score(X_test, y_test)))
print("------------------------------")
print("Model training score with C=1:\n{:.3f}".format(clf4.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Model testing score with C=1:\n{:.3f}".format(clf4.score(X_test, y_test)))
print("------------------------------")
print("Model training score with C=10:\n{:.3f}".format(clf5.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Model testing score with C=10:\n{:.3f}".format(clf5.score(X_test, y_test)))
print("------------------------------")
print("Model training score with C=100:\n{:.3f}".format(clf6.score(X_train, y_train)))
print("Model testing score with C=100:\n{:.3f}".format(clf6.score(X_test, y_test)))
```

When I run this code, I get certain scores per different regularization parameter C. When I would run the .fit lines again (aka train them again), these scores turn out completely different. Sometimes they are even way different (e.g. 72% vs. 90% for the same value of C).

Where does this variability come from? I thought that, assuming I use the same random_state parameter, it would always find the same support vectors and hence would give me the same results, but since the score changes when I train the model another time, this is not the case.
In logistic regression, for instance, the scores are always consistent, no matter if I run the fit. code again.

Explaining this variability in accuracy score would be of much help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course. **You need to fix the `random_state=None` to a specific seed so that you can reproduce the results.**

Otherwise, you use the default `random_state=None` and thus, every time you call the commands, a random seed is used and this is why you get this variability.

---

Use:

```
cancer = load_breast_cancer()
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(cancer.data, cancer.target, 
                                                    stratify=cancer.target, random_state=42)
clf2 = LinearSVC(C=0.01,random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf3 = LinearSVC(C=0.1, random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf4 = LinearSVC(C=1,   random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf5 = LinearSVC(C=10,  random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
clf6 = LinearSVC(C=100, random_state=42).fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Comment: Makes sense, thanks! Though, why don't I have to specify the random state per model when I create similar models with different C values for logistic regression?

Comment: You have. but if you get the same results it means that the results and estimations are invariant to the C parameter. Under other settings, the results would never be the same without fixing the random seed.

Comment: This random_state inside the model parameters indicate which pseudo random number is used to start the gradient coordinate descent, and therefore they must be the same across all models if you want to evaluate those. While the random_state inside the train_test_split function covers how the train/test data is randomly drawn. Is this correct?